# Recognizing subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $H$ subgroup of $G$:

> $G = <\mathbb R,+>, H = \{\log{a}: a \in \mathbb Q, a>0\}$.

$\log{a} + \log{b} = \log{(ab)}$. If $a$ and $b$ are positive rationals, so is $ab$. Since the range of $log$ is $\mathbb R$, both $\log{(ab)}$ and $-\log{a}$ are in $H$. So $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb R$.

> $G = <\mathbb R,+>, H = \{\log{n}: n \in \mathbb Z, n>0\}$.

The argument above works for any $n > 0 \in \mathbb Z$ too.

> $G = <\mathbb R,+>, H = {x \in \mathbb R: \tan{x} \in \mathbb Q}$.

$\tan{(x + y)} = \frac {(\tan{x} + \tan{y})}{1 - \tan{x}\tan{y}}$. Let $x = \frac \pi4$ and $y = \frac {5pi}{4}$. Then, $\tan{(x + y)}$ is undefined. So, $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

> $G = <\mathbb R*, >, H= \{2^n3^m: m,n \in \mathbb Z\}.$

The inverse of $2^n3^m$ is  $3^{-m}2^{-n}$ and $(-m - n) \in \mathbb Z$. Also, $2^n3^m \cdot 2^p3^q \in \mathbb Z$ since $p, q \in \mathbb Z.$ So, $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$

> $G = <\mathbb R \times \mathbb R, + >, H = \{(x,y): y = 2x\}$.

$(x, y) + (x, y) = (2x, 2y) = (2x, 2(2x)).$ Also, $-(x, y) = (-x, -y) = (-x, -2x),$ so $-y = -2x \to y = 2x.$ Thus, $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$

> $G=<\mathbb R \times \mathbb R, +>, H= \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 > 0 \}$.

$(x, y) + (x, y) = (2x, 2y).$ So, $(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 > 0.$  Also,  $(-x)^2 + (-y)^2 > 0$. Thus, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Please, see if any of that is correct.

Comment: With the last two examples, don't use the same ordered pair to check closure. Use $(x,y)$ and $(x', y')$ or some variant of that.

Comment: In your last example, does $H$ have an additive identity?

Comment: @ David Wheeler, not sure. $(0, 0)$ is not in $H$, so that can't be it. Gotta think a bit.

Comment: Well, it is a theorem (try to prove it!) that the identity of a subgroup $H < G$ is the SAME as the identity element of $G$. So, if the identity of $G$ isn't in $H$, you're "fluxored".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful,in the first two examples you are forgetting to check if additive inverses are in the set.  For $H=\{\log a:a\in\Bbb Q,a>0\}$ additive inverses are included.
$$-\log a=\log a^{-1}=\log\frac1a.$$

However for $H=\{\log a:a\in\Bbb Z,a>0\}$, additive inverses are not included, since for any 
$a\in \Bbb Z$ with $a>1$, $a^{-1}$ is not in the set.

Comment: Yes, it seems that OP is using the finite subgroup test: That $H \leq G$ if $gh \in H$ whenever $g, h \in G$. This is not enough for infinite groups, as we're seeing here :)

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend that in checking if $H$ is a subgroup, you use the *one-step subgroup test*:

$a,b \in H \implies a\ast b^{-1} \in H$. This checks closure, existence of identity, and  existence  of inverses all in one fell swoop.

For example, with $H = \{2^n3^m: m,n \in \Bbb Z\}$ we have:

$(2^n3^m)(2^{-n'}3^{-m'}) = 2^{n-n'}3^{m-m'}$ and $n-n',m-m'$ are in $\Bbb Z$ whenever $n,n',m,m'$ are (by a similar one-step test applied to $\Bbb Z$ under addition).

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.